# Why would a VB6 app cut off controls from the bottom of the form when building the app on a build agent?

Tags: forms, build, vb6

We have an old VB6 application that is occasionally updated, and we noticed recently that we intermittently have problems with controls being cut off from the bottom of the form (e.g. OK / Cancel buttons only show the top).

[image: Image showing top of buttons]

When the dev team compile the application on their desktops and run it, the form looks fine.  However, when we build the application on our build agent (kicked off via Jenkins), we are finding that the controls on the bottom of the form are cut off.

We had a Prod build in May, and the screen was fine.  Since then, we've had another update which needed to be deployed to Prod, however this time the controls are cut off.  My colleague seems to think that the way to resolve this issue is kick off the build via Jenkins, open a Remote Desktop session on the build agent while the build is running, with the screen maximised.

Why would this be a fix?  Is there a way around this?  Ideally we'd like to be able to kick off a build via Jenkins and have the process complete automatically, and not require a manual step of opening a remote connection each time.

Any advice would be appreciated :)  Thanks.

Comment: Easiest fix is to do `Width = XXXX` and `Height = YYYY` on the first couple lines of your `Form_Load`, assuming the form is not sizeable.  You can get these values off of the Properties panel once you have it the size you want.  It may adjust itself in the IDE, but it will always force itself to the proper size when displayed.

Comment: Are you seeing any (automatic / unexpected) modifications made to the FRM files?

Comment: @User51 We've discussed some options like this with the Devs, but there is a lot of "red tape" to work through with regards to any modification of the screen :(

Comment: @StayOnTarget no unexpected modifications

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm no expert on that matter, but I've pieced that much together in the past:

It has to do with the `ScaleMode` property of the form, which defaults to `Twips`. MSDN states that

> **twip** A screen-independent, absolute unit of measurement (such as an inch or a centimeter). A twip is a unit of length equal to 1/20 of
> a printer's point, and a printer's point is 1/72 of an inch. There are
> approximately 1440 twips to a logical inch or 567 twips to a logical
> centimeter (the length of a screen item measuring one inch or one
> centimeter when printed).

Looking at [this posting](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2366246-scalemode-in-vb6), it also seem to depend on the screen resolution.

So I'd make sure the dev/build machines share the same settings.

Comment: Thanks,  I've been doing some more digging and it turns out that a number of users have been logging on to the build agent under different user ID's when the build is running, which I guess could be the root cause.  

Guess we need to find a way to lock the resolution somehow...???

Comment: @Newbie_Hewie at this point you could either edit your question to note that scalemode is the probably culprit and ask how to make the app resilient to that; or just post a new question.\